# D3 scaleTime() axis tick misalignment

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am drawing an x axis with `d3.axisBottom()` and `d3.scaleTime()`. However, the axis ticks are not aligned with the output from the scale.

Example: see this [observable notebook](https://observablehq.com/@xiaohk/time-scale-x-scale-misalignment).

```js
const width = 300;
const content = svg.append("g").attr("class", "content");

const xScale = d3.scaleTime().domain(dateExtent).range([0, 600]);
const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(10);

content
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "x-axis-group")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${width - 35})`)
  .call(xAxis);

content
  .selectAll("circle.temp-circle")
  .data(dateData)
  .join("circle")
  .attr("class", "temp-circle")
  .attr("cx", (d) => xScale(d.date))
  .attr("cy", width - 45)
  .attr("r", 3)
  .style("fill", "steelBlue");
```

Any suggestions are appreciated on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `scaleTime` and you are in the east coast of Australia, you will be somewhere between 9-11 hours ahead of Greenwich Mean Time (e.g. London, UK). `new Date` will use your local time and the for example, the first date will no longer be March 1st at midnight but February 28th at maybe 2pm.

Use [`scaleUtc`](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#scaleUtc) instead so that differences between the dates in your data and the local date of your users is not an issue (unless it's important).

> ## d3.scaleUtc([[domain, ]range]) · Source, Examples
>
> Equivalent to scaleTime, but the returned time scale operates in
> Coordinated Universal Time rather than local time.

```js
const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 500).attr("height", 300);
const content = svg.append("g").attr("class", "content");

const xScale = d3.scaleTime().domain(dateExtent).range([0, 400]);
const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(10);

// your problem
content
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "x-axis-group")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${45})`)
  .call(xAxis);

content
  .selectAll("circle.temp-circle")
  .data(dateData)
  .join("circle")
  .attr("class", "temp-circle")
  .attr("cx", (d) => xScale(d.date))
  .attr("cy", 45)
  .attr("r", 4)
  .style("fill", "steelBlue");

// using scaleUtc
const xScale2 = d3.scaleUtc().domain(dateExtent).range([0, 400]);
const xAxis2 = d3.axisBottom(xScale2).ticks(10);

content
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "x-axis-group2")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${105})`)
  .call(xAxis2);

content
  .selectAll("circle.temp-circle2")
  .data(dateData)
  .join("circle")
  .attr("class", "temp-circle2")
  .attr("cx", (d) => xScale2(d.date))
  .attr("cy", 105)
  .attr("r", 4)
  .style("fill", "steelBlue");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
const timelineData = [
  [20220301, 100],
  [20220302, 100],
  [20220303, 100],
  [20220304, 100],
  [20220305, 100],
  [20220306, 100],
  [20220307, 100],
  [20220308, 100],
  [20220309, 100],
  [20220310, 100],
  [20220311, 100],
  [20220312, 100],
  [20220313, 100],
  [20220314, 100],
  [20220315, 100],
  [20220316, 100]
];

const dateData = timelineData
  .map((d) => {
    const datePattern = /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/;
    return {
      date: new Date(String(d[0]).replace(datePattern, "$1-$2-$3")),
      count: d[1]
    };
  })
  .sort((a, b) => (a.date < b.date ? -1 : 1));

const dateExtent = d3.extent(dateData, (x) => x.date);
dateExtent[0] = new Date(
  new Date(dateExtent[0].valueOf()).setDate(dateExtent[0].getDate() - 1)
);
dateExtent[1] = new Date(
  new Date(dateExtent[1].valueOf()).setDate(dateExtent[1].getDate() + 1)
);
</script>
```